# Send email if a database record inserted time is older than 10 minutes

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have SQL table which store the data of processing jobs ( not SQL jobs. Jobs in our system). I want to get an alert if particular job is older than 10 minutes with out processing

I have property of jobsubmittedtime. 
If `DateDiff(minutes,jobsubmittedtime,GETDATE())>10` I want an email trigger

What is the best way of achieving this

Comment: How about creating job `supervise_other_jobs` run in schedule 10 min, query your table with `where DateDiff(minutes,jobsubmittedtime,GETDATE())>10` and send result to email?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am working on that

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
where jobsubmittedtime > DATEADD(MINUTE, -10, GETDATE())
```

This will allow the query to optimize based on a range scan.

If you instead wrote:

```
where DATEDIFF(MINUTE, jobsubmittedtime, GETDATE()) > 10
```

then SQL Server may choose to do a full table scan to run that procedure on every row to calculate DATEDIFF() and isn't nearly as efficient as the first approach. In general, try to do calculations on constants and input variables as opposed to the row values. Sometimes it isn't avoidable, but you get the point.